# What is the difference between "Truffle Develop" and "Ethereumjs TestRPC"?

Tags: blockchain

What is the difference in using "Truffle Develop" and "Ethereumjs TestRPC"?  While Ethereumjs-TestRPC runs an in-memory blockchain, I am curious about how "Truffle Develop" works.